# pound: multiple domains

Tags: ssl, virtualhost, pound

I've been using pound to run mydomain.dk. Now I've bought some other domains and SSL certificates that are mydomain.no, mydomain.se and mydomain.eu. My old config looked roughly like this:

```
ListenHTTPS
        Address 81.19.246.120
        Port    443
        Cert    "/usr/local/etc/pound.keys/mydomain.dk.pem"

        Service
                BackEnd
                Address 10.0.10.10
                Port    8080
                End
        End
End
```

At places like [here](http://www.ossramblings.com/pound_proxy_for_flexibility_and_security) I've seen that I can use HeadRequire in the Service part, but I want the Host header to go together with the Cert, ideally something like

```
ListenHTTPS
        Address 81.19.246.120
        Port    443
        HostAndCert    "mydomain.dk" "/usr/local/etc/pound.keys/mydomain.dk.pem"
        HostAndCert    "mydomain.se" "/usr/local/etc/pound.keys/mydomain.se.pem"
        HostAndCert    "mydomain.no" "/usr/local/etc/pound.keys/mydomain.no.pem"
        HostAndCert    "mydomain.eu" "/usr/local/etc/pound.keys/mydomain.eu.pem"

        Service
                BackEnd
                Address 10.0.10.10
                Port    8080
                End
        End
End
```

Any suggestions or clues to how I can accomplish this?

Cheers

Nik

EDIT: Yup, at http://www.apsis.ch/pound/ I see that it can't be done, one IP pr SSL domain is required. Are there good alternatives when I can't use wildcard SSLs that say mydomain.* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until Server Name Indication is supported, your best option is to get a [Unified Communications Certificate](http://www.sslshopper.com/unified-communications-uc-ssl-certificates.html) that includes all the names that you need to secure in one cert.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new feature of TLS to solve this problem: [Server Name Indication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication).
It's not widely supported yet.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a post on a very old story, but I may bring some elements of solution here:

I have read at [pound official website](http://www.apsis.ch/pound) on their 'update June 2010' that pound is able to proceed to openssl SNI (Server Name Indication) which makes it possible to build a https reverse proxy.

Furthermore, in the pound mailing-list (in which I have been totally unable to register :O) I have read that someone accomplished this [success SNI with pound](http://www.apsis.ch/pound/pound_list/archive/2011/2011-06/1309186898000#1309186898000).
I am on Linux and my browser is sni capable as reported by [this check](https://sni.velox.ch/).

However, it seems that only the first certificate specified in pound configuration file is taken in account. In fact, I have exactly the same problem as reported [here](http://www.apsis.ch/pound/pound_list/archive/2011/2011-10/1319110163000#1319110163000): The first certificate is shown to the client, if it is related to the domain name, this is fine, else, no more certificate is tried and a warning is shown on the client browser.

My configuration is like this:

```
ListenHTTPS
  Address 172.23.1.2
  Port  443
  Cert "/etc/pound/ssl/wiki.pem"
  Cert "/etc/pound/ssl/frontend.pem"

  Service
      HeadRequire "Host: .*wiki.mydomain.net.*"
      BackEnd
          Address 192.168.0.110
          Port 8080 
      End
  End
  Service
      HeadRequire "Host: .*mydomain.net.*"
      Backend
          Address 192.168.0.103
          Port 8080
      End
  End
End
```

Does anyone knows how to force each certificate to be checked until a appropriate one is getting found?

Comment: Reading pound man page: next Cert directive are allowed only if the openssl version you have on pound server handle SNI.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to say that as far as I am aware you can only have *.mydomain.com you cannot have mydomain.*

There is no alternative I know of, you must have one IP address for one SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your answer,

Such a feature does exist regarding [wikipedia_SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication).

Unfortunately, all browser and OS does not support this, but as I wrote, I am running on an OS and browser which do allow this. Roughly speaking, you must be running on a browser which include a openssl library allowing this feature (vista or more recent) or a browser implementing it (Firefox > 3 for instance).

And the examples I shown seem to prove that such a think is possible with pound. This is what we would like to realize.